# how to select or load between different tables in workspace

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a *.mat file with some tables included.I want to load each table one by one and then plot it so that the figures of each table update on one single figure .Please tell me if i am not clear ...I though this code must have been enough but it is not working when i asked it to load one table  ... please guide me why and how i should improve the code ?
Thank you

```
filename = uigetfile
load(filename)
c=who('Hs*' )   % all the tables which starts with Hs
cc=numel(c) % count the number of desired tables in MAT file which we loaded before
for i=1: cc
b=load(filename,c(i));
contour(b,60)
end
```

Comment: Would you tell us what Matlab says about the error? Any error information rather than simply "it is not working" is much much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see at least three errors in your code.

1. After the first load you don't clear the mat file, and hence all tables are still in the memory.
2. `c` is a cell array, and you shoud index it by using brackets (i.e. `c{i}`).
3. By default each plot in a figure deletes the previous one. Writing `figure(); hold on;` before the `for` loop shoud fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks Jommy for the answer, it knows  **b** as **struct** and that is why it can not plot matrice **b**  i guess... :(  i need **b** to be a 27x45 single value not  a 1x1 struct , and i don't know what to do

Comment: Maybe you can try something like `B = getfield(b, c{i});`.

Comment: yes it helped ! thank you . but i just have the last plot in figure windows , is there a way that i can see the figure windows updating in each step ? and will you pls tell me how to clear the mat file from memory which you mentioned before? many many thanks

Comment: it is ploting all the tables in one figure !!! i need it to clear the previous plot and plot the new one . i want it to illustrate tables like movie frames ! :)

Comment: Writing `drawnow(); pause(1);` just after the call to `contour` should give you the desired result.

Comment: I don't understant why you want to load the variables one at a time, since they clearly don't overlap each other, but you can achieve this result with `clearvars -except filename c cc`.

Comment: Thanks . it worked ! when i use **image** instead of contour , just blue screen ! should i change any setting ?

Comment: I guess so, but keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not intended for comment, and since this question is rapidly going off-topic it's better if you open another question.